# Jakarta EE Dependency Injection implementation

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

As you know Jakarta EE is all about specifications. Their implementations vary from solution to solution.

There is Hibernate for **JPA**. There is Tomcat for **Jakarta Servlets**.

I need Implementation of **Jakarta Dependency Injection**, but can't find one. Does anybody know what solutions are there for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either JBoss Weld, GlassFish HK2 or Apache OpenWebBeans

Comment: Which one is recommended? More stable

Comment: All of them are stable, but I would recommend starting with Weld